# Geometry Nodes result not rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, geometry-nodes

I created this scene using geometry nodes. It looks fine using cycles in the viewport.

[image]

However, as soon as I render it, everything disappears and only the background plane is visible.

[image]

Every single layer is activated for rendering so I'm not really sure what is going on here.

[image]

Here is the node setup used:

[image]

And the file in case you want to have a look:
[image]

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are instancing on this:

[image]

but this collection isn't in your scene:

[image]

i assume you made a new collection and/or renamed, so change that collection in that node to:

```
todos conjuntos paletes
```

and then change the render visibility of them to on:

[image]

then render:

[image]